# response.url changing to "http://127.0.0.1:8000" URL after a validation error on the backend PYTHON

Tags: python, python-requests

When I want to make requests.patch with a "name" value that does not comply with the requirements of validation, response.url is changing to "http://127.0.0.1:8000" and after that, response.status_code becomes 200, and my condition in if didn't work.

```
domain = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1'

async def rename_country(self, name: str, username: str):
  data = {"name": name}
  url = f"{self.domain}/country/{username}"

  response = requests.patch(url, json=data, headers=self.headers)
        
  if not response.ok:
    raise Exception(response.json()['message'])
  
  return response.json()
```

I need the URL not to be replaced and my condition to be executed on a validation error on the backend

Comment: `requests.patch` automatically follows redirects. You can [disable this behavior](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) by supplying `requests.patch(..., allow_redirects=False)`. However, your API _shouldn't_ be redirecting for invalid input - it should return a 400 status code.